# Why Allah's not interferes & helps children?

Tags: allah

Salam,

Why Allah is not interfering & helping specifically less than 3-year-old children affected by war in Gaza?

Why is Allah testing less than three years old? I'm not able to digest it.

I'm afraid to make Dua nowadays because I'm not getting if Allah not helping less than three years old then how Allah will help me?

Feeling troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

Death can happen anytime to any person by the will of Allah by various causes, not necessarily war. Allah has given free will to people and people can start war and create violence in earth, Allah is witness to all and by his will, he allows them to happen. Finally he will judge everyone.

> Corruption has appeared on land and sea because of the evil which
> men’s hands have done: and so He will make them taste the fruit of
> some of their doings, so that they may turn back from evil. [Quran 30:41](https://quran.com/en/30/41)

> Whenever they kindle the fire of war, Allah puts it out. And they
> strive to spread corruption in the land. And Allah does not like
> corruptors. [Quran 5:64](https://quran.com/en/5/64)

In Quran, you can see the story of pharaoh (firon), who ordered to kill all male children who are born for bani israel tribe. Even though it was ordered by pharaoh, it is described in Quran as a test from Allah, which means Allah allowed the cruelty of pharoah to take place but for those inflicted it was a trial. If they bear it with patience, they will get rewarded in hereafter.

> Remember when We delivered you from Pharaoh’s people, who subjected
> you to grievous torment, **slaying your sons** and sparing only your
> daughters—surely in that there was a great **trial for you from your
> Lord**— [Quran 2:49](https://quran.com/2/49)

So we should never loose hope of Allah's mercy and always continue to pray

> And do not become faint of heart, nor grieve—you will have the upper
> hand, if you are believers— [Quran 3:139](https://quran.com/3/139)

Comment: Sorry. What kind of test or faith Allah's craves for or Why Allah deficient of faith checkers. I agreed if that applies beyond 18 yrs age. But that"s completely not digestable to me if its for less than 3 yrs old. Don't you think Allah not responding at all to prayers. Call upon me i will respond. Al shifa Al sayeed. Allah is simply watching why not interferes?

Comment: Children will go to paradise, Insha Allah, as they did not have to go any trial.